# Question about Entry Source DE using Attribute Group

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, attribute

So I was building a journey with the entry source as a DE where the data in that DE would be populated by a cloudpage.  There would be emails sent for confirmation on submit.

I was told that this would not work because it would only be a "snapshot" in time.

The way to go about this is to use attribute groups in journey builder where the data would be "constantly" reviewed if that is the correct term to use - so that people would be eligible for the confirmation email closer to the event date.

Can anyone point to why this is the case?  Are contact builder-attribute groups the best entry sources to use when launching journeys that have "retroactive" rules like looking if someone has registered or not - then sending an email ex. you launch a journey then 5 days later they register.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is called "Contact Data" and "Journey Data", you can check their comparison both [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5) and a simple example [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5&language=en_US):

| Journey Data | Contact Data |
| --- | --- |
| Initial data value about a customer | Current data value about a customer |
| Provides attributes in the state they were in when the contact entered the journey | Provides attributes in the state they are in when evaluation occurs after the entry event has fired |
| Comprised of event data and activity data | - |
| Use when a contact is likely to exist in a journey more than once simultaneously | - |
| Use for comparison when a data value is expected to change | - |

I would say that choosing "Contact Data" is the way for the majority of cases since it is better to have fresh data. Yet, there are some journeys that actually require you to have "Journey Data" to be compared with "Contact Data" in order to see if the subscriber has done some action or not.